# Parse urlencoded data in Elixir (without Plug.Parsers)

Tags: elixir

Not the most efficient way, but as for practice, I would like to parse params from urlencoded data in a POST request.

I'm new to the concept of pattern matching and Erlang/Elixir syntax, so I managed to create the following code:

```
defmodule DataParser do

    def urlEncodedParse(body) do
        Regex.split(~r/&/, body) 
            |> Enum.map(fn(data) -> { 
                String.to_atom(hd(Regex.split(~r/=/, data))), 
                List.last(Regex.split(~r/=/, data))
            } end)
    end

end
```

Running it:

```
iex(4)> body = "key=asdasd123123&name=Leonidas&country=Sparta"
"key=asdasd123123&name=Leonidas&country=Sparta"

iex(6)> params = DataParser.urlEncodedParse(body)
[key: "asdasd123123", name: "Leonidas", country: "Sparta"]

iex(8)> params[:name]
"Leonidas"
```

But I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this.
I'm also aware I could use Plug.Parsers to achieve the same goal, just wondering how much can be done with less dependencies as possible.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You've got working code there. Stack Overflow works best when you're asking about solving something that you haven't already figured out. That being said, do you need to handle `+` or  `%` encoded characters?

Comment: @CoderDennis If I understood you right. I don't need to handle '+' or '%' characters for now, but it would be great if there was a solution to parse special characters as well.

Comment: OK. I'm still not sure what you're asking. What problem are you having that you need help with? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Side note: you should not use atoms for data structures that are derived from arbitrary user input. They are never garbage collected so a malicious client could flood your entire memory with your current implementation. Just stick with strings. Other than that, I would really not bother with implementing such low level details yourself. If someone else did the work already, why reinvent the wheel? Ignore the last sentence if you view this just as an exercise, but please don't ship it to production :)

Comment: Just use URI.decode_query/2 or take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.0.5/lib/elixir/lib/uri.ex#L97) for it.

Answer (score 0):

use URI.decode_query/2 instead 
more detail at https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#decode_query/2

Comment: Your answer would be much complete if you can elaborate `URI.decode_query/2`. Also instead of adding the link, try to quote whats needed as links are tend to die after some time. Thanks